# Filestreams reading and writing to text file, then convert to binary in c++

Tags: file-io, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

What I am trying to do is fairly elementary however I am having trouble with my project. My project is too large to include everything, so I will just include the two functions that I am writing along with what the txt file looks like. This is in c++.

bookmark.cfg

```
No Title 
0 0 0 0 0 0

No Title 
1 1 1 1 1 1

No Title 
2 2 2 2 2 2

No Title 
3 3 3 3 3 3

No Title 
4 4 4 4 4 4

No Title 
5 5 5 5 5 5
```

These are my two functions for writing and reading to the text file and my class's private structure

```
struct BookMark {
    std::string strFilename;
    unsigned id;
    unsigned bookID;
    unsigned chapterNumber;
    unsigned pageNumber;
    unsigned lineNumber;
    unsigned columnNumber;
}; // BookMark

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// readConfigFile()
bool BookManager::readConfigFile() {
    using namespace std;

    // Just To Be Safe Incase This Function Is Called In Multiple Places
    _mBookMarks.clear();

    ifstream inFile( _strConfigFilename );
    if ( inFile.fail() ) {
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " failed, could not open " )     + _strConfigFilename + std::string( " \nfor reading in book mark information \nInvalid file or file does not exist" ) );
    }

    // Read In The Book Mark Contents
    std::vector<BookMark> vBookMarks;
    BookMark bookMark;
    string tempString = "";

    if ( inFile.is_open() ) {
        while ( !inFile.eof() ) {
            BookMark bookMark;
            getline( inFile, bookMark.strFilename );
            inFile >> bookMark.id;
            inFile >> bookMark.bookID;
            inFile >> bookMark.chapterNumber;
            inFile >> bookMark.pageNumber;
            inFile >> bookMark.lineNumber;
            inFile >> bookMark.columnNumber;
            getline( iniFile, tempString );
            //_mBookMarks.insert( make_pair( bookMark.id, bookMark ) );
           vBookMarks.push_back( bookMark );
        }
    }

    inFile.close(); 

    return true;
} // readConfigFile



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// writeConfigFile()
bool BookManager::writeConfigFile() {
    using namespace std;

    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open( _strConfigFilename, fstream::out );
    if ( outFile.fail() ) {
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " failed, could not open " )     + _strConfigFilename + std::string( " \nfor writing book mark contents to file." ) );
    }

    // Write Out Book Mark Contents
    if ( outFile.is_open() ) {
        unsigned i = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < _mBookMarks.size(); i++ ) {
            outFile << _mBookMarks.at( i ).strFilename      << endl;
            outFile << _mBookMarks.at( i ).id               << " ";
            outFile << _mBookMarks.at( i ).bookID           << " ";
            outFile << _mBookMarks.at( i ).chapterNumber    << " "; 
            outFile << _mBookMarks.at( i ).pageNumber       << " ";
            outFile << _mBookMarks.at( i ).lineNumber       << " "; 
            outFile << _mBookMarks.at( i ).columnNumber     << endl << endl;            
        }
    }

    outFile.close();

    return true;
}  // writeConfigFile
```

The problem I am having is, when I call the write function all the text is being displayed properly in my text file. The first line should be a string that contains the book's title or filename. The second line should be all unsigned ints to specify parameters to know the position of the bookmark's location. As of now I just populated my classes structure with arbitrary data using a for loop and incrementing each bookmarks parameters just to test these functions. Somewhere else in my code I call my write method first to create this text file and write the contents. This seems to be working fine. Then I call my read method to read in the file and populate a temporary vector of my structure to see if the contents being read from the file are valid. Once I get this to work properly I'll then just populate my class's member variable structure instead.

Here I am reading in the first line using getline function then I am using the stream operators to get the rest of the contents. While I am debugging my code going through the read method and checking my temp vector the first element has the correct value with No Title and each of the parameters are 0. When I check the next element there is no string in the next BookMark structure object and all values are 0. Also there should only be 5 elements in my temp vector and it should break out of the loop, but it continues and never breaks out of the loop. Why is the code behaving like this? What is it that I am doing wrong? How can I change this to get the behavior I am looking for?

If you need to see this class in full let me know, but I think the rest of the class is not important as to what I am trying to do, only these two functions should be enough to describe my situation. Once I get this to work properly then I'll just change the read and write methods to work in binary as opposed to text.

Comment: Please indicate the language this is written in.

Comment: from the looks of the write function your writing and empty line in between each bookmark structure, however you don't account for the empty line in your read method

Comment: I know what you are saying, I have tried this with a temp string and used getline( this filestream, tempString ) and was getting the same results

Comment: I just edited my original post adding in the tempstring for the newline after each structure read.

Comment: To let you know, I am using windows 7 with visual studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved my own problem. In my read method, I had to add a second getline( this fileStream, tempString ); And now my code appears to be working properly. My vector has the correct values and it only has 5 elements and now breaks out of the loop.